# Using Pandoc to include epub TOC in HTML output?

Tags: html, latex, markdown, pandoc, epub

Pandoc noob here, I'm having trouble getting a table of contents into HTML output.

My input is a .epub file.

I've added the `--toc` flag, and `--standalone`. My header template includes a `$toc$` block as well.

The html output file does have proper html headings (h1, h2, etc), so I know that the structure is there.

But there's no TOC appearing in the outputted HTML file. How might I get this to appear? Or is this not possible in Pandoc from a .epub file?

---

EDIT to add detail per request in comments.

My `header.html` is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  </head>
  <style>
      img {
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto;
      }
      body {
          font-family: sans-serif;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div>$table-of-contents$</div>
    <div>$body$</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The empty first `div` where `$toc$` is in the template comes through in the HTML output, but empty.

The output itself is normal, the included css works, but it's just missing any toc.

I'm calling it like this:

`pandoc --standalone input.epub -o output.html --extract-media=. --template=header.html --toc`

Even when I used the default html pandoc template with `--toc`, no table of contents would come through. But it did come through with the `--toc` command when converting the same .epub to pdf using latex.

Comment: works for me for a random epub with pandoc 2.10.1...

Comment: It may help us to debug your issue if you could share more excerpts from your code, the header template or perhaps what's being generated in the output. The more you can share, the easier it will be to help :)

Comment: @defines added some clarification as an edit to my original question :)

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue now